# Unity - Input Field -Virtual keyboard auto hide when lost focus

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have implement virtual keyboard on android . I use Input Field to show keyboard. But when keyboard is showed i touch some where on screen , so the keyboard auto hide . I want to the keyboard only hide when i press enter/done on virtual keyboard. How can i do it ?. I found [it](https://answers.unity.com/questions/915514/keep-inputfield-focus-selected-when-clicking-a-but.html) the same problem but in doesn't solve my problem/I use unity 2019.2.x and android 9.